# ModemManager crashes everytime I run FernPro to perform wireless testing

Tags: networking, 16.04

first time posting on this forum, so apologies if this has already been answered. I have searched for similar issues but have not found a solution as yet.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell Inspiron 15 (7000 Series) laptop. I have connected a USB ALFA 802.11b/g/n long range wireless dongle and installed Fern-Pro to perform wireless testing. I have a fully updated system with the latest available OS and software upgrades (as of 18th July).

Every time I fire up the ALFA in monitor mode ModemManager crashes and crashses Fern-Pro.

Dmesg shows :

```
[ 1946.433748] ModemManager[862]: segfault at 0 ip 0000000000431ab3 sp  00007ffcf3e31520 error 4 in ModemManager[400000+103000]
[ 1947.700364] device mon0 entered promiscuous mode
[ 2295.555405] ModemManager[8840]: segfault at 0 ip 0000000000431ab3 sp 00007fff30ccc870 error 4 in ModemManager[400000+103000]
[ 2296.702307] device mon0 entered promiscuous mode
[ 2307.867223] a2a663a90e8e712[9746]: segfault at 570033 ip  00000000f70c6450 sp 00000000ffd5dfc0 error 4 in  libsqlcipher.so.0[f7043000+1af000]
```

Looks to me like a bug in ModemManager when I set the ALFA into Monitor mode.

Thanks in advance for any ideas anyone may have.